# License Plate Image Matching

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, template-matching

I would like to match two license plate images, sample images given below

[image: License plate 1]
[image: License plate 2]

Here these two license plate belong to same vehicle, hence they should give match.
There may be zoom and slight rotation in these images, also only a part of the original may be visible as given in the example.
If the License plate belong to different vehicle algorithm should say it is different.

Which is best algorithm for doing this ?

Comment: Perhaps OCR can do the trick. Will that work for you?

Comment: In most of the cases i am getting wrong results during segmentation, in such cases i am not getting correct results in OCR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you use openCV functions from Features2D Framework, and [Homography](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_homography/feature_homography.html#feature-homography) method to handle the scaling and rotation problem.  Specifically, in Features2D, there are classes that may be helpful for your to [detect the letter](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/features2d/doc/common_interfaces_of_feature_detectors.html#featuredetector), [extract](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/features2d/doc/common_interfaces_of_descriptor_extractors.html#descriptorextractor) them, and [match your two templates](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/features2d/doc/common_interfaces_of_descriptor_matchers.html#descriptormatcher) after extraction.

Comment: What all features that I can use from Features2D, for detecting and extracting the letters

Comment: Use Scale-invariant feature transform to extract the lines at different orientations for each letter. Besides,feature point extraction might help, although it is used in OCR problem, which seems much more complicated than the matching problem. Basically you can investigate the possible pixel neighborhoods: http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/feneric/charrec.html

Answer (score 1):

Frankly this is a non-trivial question.

Just to list some obvious options:

- Implement one of the numerous character recognition softwares, and
  get the string of characters, and then do a search for the substring
  in another string.
- For images with almost no difference in zoom
  level, Use edge detection filters, like canny edge detection, to
  enhance the image, then use ICP (Iterative Closest Point), letting
  each edge pixel provide a vector to the closest edge pixel in the
  other image, with a similar value. this typically aligns images if
  they are similar enough. The final score tells you how similar they
  are.
- For very large zoom levels, use multiple rotation and zoom
  hypothesis, and for each, scale the images and do cross correlation
  of the two images. select the hypothesis, that provides the
  coordinates with the best correlation, and use the point of
  correlation, as the x and y offset. The value of the correlation
  tells you how good a fit you have..

many other smarter algorithms have been produced for image fitting. However, you have much larger problems.
The two example images you provide does not show the entire licenseplate, so you will not be able to say anything better than, "the probabillity of a match is larger than zero", as the number of visible characters increase, so does the probabillity of a match.

you could argue that small damages to a license plate also increases the probabillity, in that case cross correlation or similar method is needed to evaluate the probabillity of a match.